# I cannot add service reference(WCF library) to MVC4 in VS2012

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

My problem is very simple, but unfortunately I cannot figure out what's wrong. I've created a new MVC4 Internet Application project with Razor syntax, then I added another WCF Library project to this solution. I did not make any change on these codes. However, as I added the WCF project as a service reference in the MVC 4 app, I'm getting 1 Error message and 3 Warning messages:

1. Error   4   Custom tool error: Failed to generate code for the service
   reference 'ServiceReference1'.  Please check other error and warning
   messages for details.   c:\users\vendre\documents\visual studio
   2012\Projects\MvcApplication3\MvcApplication3\Service
   References\ServiceReference1\Reference.svcmap   1   1   MvcApplication3
2. Warning 1   Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:portType Detail:
   An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension:
   System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractImporter
   Error: Could not load file or assembly 'DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet,
   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246'
   or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file
   specified.
3. Warning 2   Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:binding Detail:
   There was an error importing a wsdl:portType that the wsdl:binding
   is dependent on. XPath to wsdl:portType:
   //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:portType[@name='IService1']
4. Warning 3   Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:port Detail: There
   was an error importing a wsdl:binding that the wsdl:port is
   dependent on. XPath to wsdl:binding:
   //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:binding[@name='BasicHttpBinding_IService1']

I read some article but did not resolved my problem. If somebody know the answer for my problem, please tell me.

THX.

Comment: did you try this http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/10/29/silverlight-update-service-reference-for-a-wcf-service-generting-empty-class/

Comment: Yes I did, I tried that all the collection type, but the problem still exists. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: The error is pretty clear: **Could not load file or assembly 'DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet** - so make sure you have that/those file(s) available when you add that service reference...

Answer (score 42, accepted):

When you add the reference, on advanced setting remove the reuse types checkbox.

Comment: The solution worked great but is there an explanation of why this breaks it?

Comment: Excellent answer. @Tim: I suspect it must have something to do with the fact that the MVC4 project template may not include some assemblies that WCF proxy generation needs to "Reuse"

Comment: Great this was driving me crazy... I dont even care how nor why! (just kidding I'd like to know :))

Comment: I guess this is one of the highest [points earned] / [words typed] ratios. :-)

Comment: While this also worked for me, I agree with @Tim. It would be good to understand this, because the consequence of this solution is the possible duplication of classes in the project.

Comment: I don't know what caused this error, but if you remove that checkbox, you are not able to use types from the other project in you WS I think, so you cant use DTO objects.

Answer (score 19):

If you're experiencing this problem in 2021 with VS2019. Add a folder to the project called "Connected Services"

Comment: It was "Service References" for me. Thanks

Comment: I had to add the folder from file explorer, VS throws the error that "file" already exists

Comment: "Service References" and from file explorer - that worked!

Answer (score 7):

sometimes you need to create a folder "Service References" in project path. If you dont have this folder it should gives this path error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio 2019, I fixed the error (system cannot find path specified) by creating a new folder named "Connected Services" inside project folder

Answer (score 3):

If using VS 2019, check if in Solution Explorer you see "Service Reference". Than edit the project file for following

```
<ItemGroup>
  <WCFMetadata Include="Connected Services\" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Just to be clear, make sure you DON'T have both "Service References" and "Connected Services".

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio 2022, You need to create a folder "Connected Services" in project path, via Windows Explorer, not Visual studio solution explorer'

[image: Like this]

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. I was having this issue with the VS 2022

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me as will with VS 2019

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following :

1. Delete the "Connected Services" folder from the project in Visual Studio
2. Add the service reference with right-click on the project / Add / Service Reference...
   It should work and recreate the "Connected Services" folder with your new service reference.